# Convergence of max and min of two convergent sequences $\langle f_{n}\rangle$ and $\langle g_{n}\rangle$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $\langle f_{n}\rangle$ and  $\langle g_{n}\rangle$ are two convergent sequences and two sequences $\langle \phi_{n}\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_{n}\rangle$ are defined as:
$$\phi_{n}=\max\{f_{n},g_{n}\}$$
$$\psi_{n}=\min\{f_{n},g_{n}\}$$
Then the sequences $\langle \phi_{n}\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_{n}\rangle$ are also convergent and
$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}  \phi_{n}=\max\Big\{\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_{n},\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} g_{n}\Big\}$$
$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}  \psi_{n}=\min\Big\{\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_{n},\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} g_{n}\Big\}$$

Which two convergent sequences $\langle f_{n}\rangle$ and  $\langle g_{n}\rangle$  can I use as examples to see how this works easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_n= \frac {100}n \sin n$ and $g_n=1-\frac{100}n\sin n$ might be illustrative.